# ASP.NET Core Linux SSL - SSL Read Bio failed with OpenSSL error

Tags: c#, linux, ssl, https, asp.net-core

I'm currently developing on an asp.net core application. The application itself runs perfect under Windows using Kestrel. Now I published the application to a linux environment (Lubuntu 16.04.1 64 bit).

When making a normal http request to everything works fine.

When I call the page via https everything works fine, but the WebSocket-Connection made via wss gets closed instantly. Also figured out (Thanks to [Jon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/84539/jon)) that making a StatusCode-Response without a Response-Body produces that error. But I'm pretty sure both have different origins. The Websocket error seems to occur at the Upgrade-Response. Issue already reported to the WebSockets Github-Repo (https://github.com/aspnet/WebSockets/issues/112). The error with the StatusCode is reported [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/10858).

In program.cs I configure Kestrel to use ssl.

```
IConfigurationRoot config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/Config")
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();

        IWebHost host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseConfiguration(config)
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseKestrel(options =>
            {
                options.NoDelay = true;
                options.UseHttps(new X509Certificate2(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + config["SSL:Cert:Path"], config["SSL:Cert:Password"])); //Currently set to 'cert.pfx' with pw 'cert'
            })
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

        host.Run();
```

Ok I figured out that the problem probably is related to the WebSocket-Connection. So here a little bit more over the WebSocket.

The WebSocket is configured in Startup with the following code.

```
        app.Map("/socket", socketApp =>
        {
            socketApp.UseWebSockets(new WebSocketOptions()
            {
                KeepAliveInterval = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0)
            });

            socketApp.UseMiddleware<WebsocketServerMiddleware>();
        });
```

The important part of the WebsocketServerMiddleware:

```
        if (context.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
        {
            WebSocket socket = await context.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync();

            if (socket != null && socket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
            {
                 ArraySegment<byte> buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[4096]);
                 await socket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, CancellationToken.None);

                 ... followed by handling of the message ... gets never called
            }
        }
```

The WebSocketUrl is created in the view by this:

```
 var url = "@(Context.Request.IsHttps ? "wss" : "ws")://@Context.Request.Host/socket";
```

As mentioned before ... on windows everthing works fine ... only linux is making problems.

Here is the Stacktrace:

```
System.IO.IOException: The encryption operation failed, see inner exception. ---> Interop+OpenSsl+SslException: SSL Read BIO failed with OpenSSL error - .
   at Interop.OpenSsl.BioRead(SafeBioHandle bio, Byte[] buffer, Int32 count)
   at Interop.OpenSsl.Encrypt(SafeSslHandle context, Byte[] input, Int32 offset, Int32 count, Byte[]& output, SslErrorCode& errorCode)
   at System.Net.SslStreamPal.EncryptDecryptHelper(SafeDeleteContext securityContext, Byte[] input, Int32 offset, Int32 size, Boolean encrypt, Byte[]& output, Int32& resultSize)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Security.SslStreamInternal.StartWriting(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStreamInternal.ProcessWrite(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStreamInternal.BeginWrite(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<>c.<WriteAsync>b__86_0(Byte[] bufferArg, Int32 offsetArg, Int32 sizeArg, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncImpl[TArg1,TArg2,TArg3](Func`6 beginMethod, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, TArg1 arg1, TArg2 arg2, TArg3 arg3, Object state, TaskCreationOptions creationOptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory.FromAsync[TArg1,TArg2,TArg3](Func`6 beginMethod, Action`1 endMethod, TArg1 arg1, TArg2 arg2, TArg3 arg3, Object state)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.WriteAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Filter.Internal.StreamSocketOutput.WriteAsync(ArraySegment`1 buffer, Boolean chunk, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.Frame.<FlushAsync>d__139.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.Frame.<Microsoft-AspNetCore-Http-Features-IHttpUpgradeFeature-UpgradeAsync>d__249.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets.Server.WebSocketMiddleware.UpgradeHandshake.<AcceptAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at HomeSystem.Methods.WebsocketServerMiddleware.<Invoke>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.MapMiddleware.<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.RequestServicesContainerMiddleware.<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.Frame`1.<RequestProcessingAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
```

My openssl Version is:
OpenSSL 1.0.2g-fips  1 Mar 2016

Comment: What is the OpenSSL version on this machine?

Comment: The result of openssl version is: OpenSSL 1.0.2g-fips  1 Mar 2016

Comment: I see the same error on a non websocket request with https and kestrel

Comment: Corefx issue raised here https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/10858

Comment: The issue I describe here has to do with the WebSockets. When I disable them everything works fine. I already opened an issue for the repo of websockets: https://github.com/aspnet/WebSockets/issues/112. It seems they already know this problem.

Comment: So you're saying with https and kestrel all normal http requests are processed ok? If so can I ask how you created your certificate?

Comment: No both protocols work. But when making a request over https and using secured websockets via wss the exception occurs. So I'm using ssl but than websockets not working...

Comment: @Jon I used a self signed certificate created in iis control panel and exported as x509 in pfx Format.

Comment: I have a self signed cert and making any request to https causes that exception

Comment: @Jon I see you didn't set a password for the cert. Maybe you try it out. I cannot test it on my machine with a blank Password, because IIS prevents to use a "" as a password. Maybe you try to generate a cert with a password.

Comment: So I figured either a workaround or cause and that is if you return a body then there is no exception, if you just set a response status code and no body you get an exception

Comment: @Jon Yes you're right. Same problem on linux when only returning status code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121149/discussion-between-morris-janatzek-and-jon).